# Adding columns that contain equations to a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I am using this script to take a large csv file and separate it by unique values in the first column then save new files. I would like to also add 3 columns at the end of each file that contain calculations based on the previous columns. The columns will have headers as well. My current code is as follows

```
import csv, itertools as it, operator as op

csv_contents = []
with open('Nov15.csv', 'rb') as fin:
  file_reader = csv.DictReader(fin)   # default delimiter is comma
  print file_reader
  fieldnames = file_reader.fieldnames # save for writing
  for line in file_reader:            # read in all of your data
    csv_contents.append(line)         # gather data into a list (of dicts)

# input to itertools.groupby must be sorted by the grouping value 
sorted_csv_contents = sorted(csv_contents, key=op.itemgetter('Object'))

for groupkey, groupdata in it.groupby(sorted_csv_contents, key=op.itemgetter('Object')):
    with open('slice_{:s}.csv'.format(groupkey), 'wb') as gips:
        file_writer = csv.DictWriter(gips, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        file_writer.writeheader()         
        file_writer.writerows(groupdata)
```

Comment: Where is this code attempting to add the 3 columns, and how specifically is it not working?

Comment: I haven't added the code to add the 3 columns because I couldn't figure out how. From searching there were many explanations on how to add rows but not columns. All I have been able to do is splice the original file by unique texts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your comments are true, you could probably do it like this (for imaginary columns `col1`, `col2`, and the calculation `col1 * col2`:

```
for line in file_reader:  # read in all of your data
    line['calculated_col0'] = line['col1'] * line['col2']
    csv_contents.append(line)  # gather data into a list (of dicts)
```

Comment: I received an error when I added that line to program "KeyError: 'col1'

Comment: Of course. `col1` is just a made up. I can't possibly know which columns you have in your data. `I would like to also add 3 columns at the end of each file that contain calculations based on the previous columns`. `col1` and `col2` is supposed to be your previous columns, and `*` is the calculation.

Comment: Oh well that was stupid of me haha. Thank you. I am pretty new to all this.

Comment: If you receive a solution on a question, it is generally a good idea to accept the appropriate answer so other people can see that you no longer need help. This keeps Stackoverflow *neat* and *clean*, and awards the person whose answer you choose as your solution some imaginary Internet-points!